# What are the scopes of default template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, scope, c++14, default

The standard (§14.1) Template parameters says:

> A template-parameter of a template template-parameter is permitted to have a default template-argument.

Now consider following code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A {};
struct B {};

template<typename T = A>
struct X;

template<>
struct X<A> {
   static void f() { cout << 1 << endl; }
};

template<>
struct X<B> {
   static void f() { cout << 2 << endl; }
};

template< template<typename T = B> class C>
void g() {
   C<>::f();
}

int main() {
   g<X>();
}
```

It's output is:

> out put :2

In this case, the template template-parameter is `C`.
But I don't understand why  `C<B>::f()` is called inside `g()`.

Comment: The same thing happens if you do `template < template <int = 0> class C> struct A{ void foo() { cout << C<>{}.get(); }};`, then `template <int n = 1> struct B { int get() { return n; } };` and then `A<B>{}.foo();` prints `0` and not `1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This declaration

```
template< template<typename T = B> class C>
void g() {
   C<>::f();
}
```

is equivalent to

```
template< template<typename T = B> class C>
void g() {
   C<B>::f();
}
```

Thus this call

```
   g<X>();
```

is equivalent to the call of the function

```
void g() {
   X<B>::f();
}
```

The paragraph #14.1.14 of the C++ Standard contains corresponding examples

> 14 A template-parameter of a template template-parameter is permitted
>   to have a default template-argument. When such default arguments are
>   speciﬁed, they apply to the template template-parameter in the scope
>   of the template template-parameter. [Example:

```
template <class T = float> struct B {}; 
template <template <class TT = float> class T> struct A {
 inline void f();
 inline void g(); 
}; 
template <template <class TT> class T> void A<T>::f() {
 T<> t; // error - TT has no default template argument 
} 
template <template <class TT = char> class T> void A<T>::g() {
 T<> t; // OK - T<char> 
}
```

> —end example]

Comment: Why is `C<>` equivalent to `C<B>` instead of `C<T>`?

Comment: @KyleStrand It uses the default argument.

Comment: @KyleStrand Actually it is equal to `C<T>`, but it happens that `T` is equal to `B` (the default argument), thus you have `C<B>`.

Comment: `C<T>` would be ill formed, `T` is not declared in the scope of the body of `g`.

Comment: @Oktalist good point , considering scope of default template arguments why    C<B>::f(); is called

Comment: The default template parameter of `X` is `A`, not `B`. Hence, `X<>::f()` is equivalent to `X<A>::f()`.

Comment: @Adib There is an example in the C++ Standard p. #14.1.14

Answer (score 4):

Think about what would happen without default template template parameter for g():

```
template< template<typename T> class C>
void g() {
   C<>::f();
}
```

would be ill-formed as the use of C would require a template parameter inside the definition of g(). Now that you provided B as a default, the definition of template g() is well formed and the default for the template template parameter of X is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is covered by [**N4567 14.1/14**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4567.pdf)

> A template-parameter of a template template-parameter is permitted to
>   have a default template-argument. When such default arguments are
>   specified, they apply to the template template-parameter in the scope
>   of the template template-parameter. [Example:

```
    template <class T = float> struct B {}; 

    template <template <class TT = float> class T>
    struct A { inline void f(); inline void g(); };

    template <template> <class TT> class T> void A<T>::f() {
      T<> t; // error - TT has no default template argument
    }

    template <template <class TT = char> class> T> void A<T>::g() {
      T<> t; // OK - T<char>
    }
```

> -- end example]

So the default template parameter of a template template parameter applies only in the scope where the default parameter is declared.
In the examples it is even switching the default template parameter for the template template parameter between the member function declaration and the member function definition.